# abort trap 6 error in C

Tags: c, memory-management, abort

I am working on an homework assignment and it compiles and run, but I keep getting this abort trap error 6 message.
Don't know why ?.

Help appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float Hello[100];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for(i = 0 ; i < 100; i++)
    {

       for(j = 0; j < 100; j++)   
       {
         Hello [i] = i + 2;

         printf("%2d : 1/(%.2f * %.2f * %.2f)\n",
         j, Hello[i], Hello[i] + 1, Hello[i] + 2);
         i += 2;
       }  

    }

 }
```

Comment: The `i += 2` will eventually make the `Hello[i]` read out of bounds